# Calculate the area of ​intersection of curves using the Monte Carlo Method in Python

Tags: python, math, simulation, computational-geometry, montecarlo

I'm making a list of exercises in which I have the following exercise:

"Use the Monte Carlo method to calculate the area of ​​intersection between the curves given below. For random number generation use the Linear Congruence Method"

[curves functions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rx4pE.png)

I'm having trouble determining the bounds of random numbers.
I already added the functions in [GeoGebra](https://www.geogebra.org/calculator/kn3hc8y5)

Comment: First of all, the question statement isn't clear. There is no such thing as an "area of intersection" of curves, what you presumably mean is the area of a certain region *bounded by* these curves. Second, it's not clear what you mean by "determining the bounds of random numbers". For this, I have no guess as to what you're trying to say

Comment: Vitor, if you mean that you don't know over what range to integrate, I think you'll have to go back to the person who posed this problem, and ask them what bounds for x and y are suitable. There doesn't appear to be any obvious choices from the diagram you linked to.

Comment: It might be helpful to note that the region that is presumably being asked about is the set of points (x,y) satisfying y ≥ x ln(x), y ≤ min{4x, cos(x)/x, cosh(x)}. This seems to be the only bounded region containing all 4 curves within its boundary

Comment: If by "determining the bounds of random numbers" you mean the bounds of the (x,y) coordinates to be (randomly) generated, and if my previous comment is correct about the region to be considered is correct, then one suitable set of (x,y) coordinates is the rectangle [0,2] x [-1,2]. It is evident from the graph that this rectangle contains the entire region of interest.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Start by plotting all four curves.  This should be doable, but the visual will help both you and anyone answering this question.

Comment: One thing is obvious: your range for x cannot include x = 0.  Two of your functions are singular at x = 0.

Answer (score 1):

Define box which contains whole area: I would say (-0.5,-0.5) to (1.5,2.0) should do it.

Sample points in the box:

```
x = -0.5 + 2*np.random.random()
y = -0.5 + 2.5*np.random.random()
```

Check against four curves if point is inside area

```
def inside(x, y):
    if ... :
         return True
    return False
```

Count ratio of points inside vs total points and multiply by box area

```
N = 100000
is_inside = 0

for k in range(0, N):
    x = -0.5 + 2*np.random.random()
    y = -0.5 + 2.5*np.random.random()

    if inside(x,y):
        is_inside += 1

area = is_inside*(2.5+0.5)*(1.5+0.5)/N
```

UPDATE

Anyway, this is good solution, I think. Python 3.10 x64 Windows 10

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

rng = np.random.default_rng(135797531)

def inside(x: np.float64, y: np.float64) -> bool:

    if x <= 0.0:
        return False

    y1 = 4.0*x
    if y > y1:
        return False

    y2 = x*np.log(x)
    if y < y2:
        return False

    y3 = np.cosh(x)
    if y > y3:
        return False

    y4 = np.cos(x) / x
    if y > y4:
        return False

    return True

x_min: np.float64 =  0.0
y_min: np.float64 = -0.5

x_max: np.float64 = 1.5
y_max: np.float64 = 2.0

N:int = 10000

is_inside:int = 0

x_plt = []
y_plt = []

for k in range(0, N):
    
    x = x_min + (x_max - x_min)*rng.random()
    y = y_min + (y_max - y_min)*rng.random()

    if inside(x,y):
        is_inside += 1
        x_plt.append(x)
        y_plt.append(y)
    
area = (x_max - x_min)*(y_max - y_min)*is_inside/N
print(area)

plt.scatter(x_plt, y_plt, s=1)
plt.show()
```

that will produce output equal to 1.18275 and plot below

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your first step should be to plot all four functions on the same graph, like this:

```
# see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76560092/calculate-the-area-of-intersection-of-curves-using-the-monte-carlo-method-in-py

import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def c1(x):
    return 4.0 * x

def c2(x):
    return x * math.log(x)

def c3(x):
    return math.cos(x) / x

def c4(x):
    return math.cosh(x)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    xmin = 0.1
    xmax = 2.0
    dx = 0.1
    X = np.arange(xmin, xmax, dx)
    y1 = list(map(c1, X))
    y2 = list(map(c2, X))
    y3 = list(map(c3, X))
    y4 = list(map(c4, X))

    # https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/plot-multiple-plots-in-matplotlib/
    plt.plot(X, y1, color='r', label='4.0*x')
    plt.plot(X, y2, color='g', label='x*ln(x)')
    plt.plot(X, y3, color='b', label='cos(x)/x')
    plt.plot(X, y4, color='m', label='cosh(x)')

    plt.xlabel('X')
    plt.ylabel('y')
    plt.legend()
    plt.show()
```

Here's the plot I get:

[image]

There's a problem that I can see: the function `x*ln(x)` lies entirely below `cosh(x)`.

Do you want the area inside the red, blue, and magenta curves?  The green curve plays no role in that case.

Do you want the area bounded by the red, blue, and green curves, with the range of x from the intersection of the red and magenta curves on the left?

Is the max value of x determined by the intersection of the blue and magenta curves?  Or the intersection of the green and blue curves?

Only you can answer those questions.  Perhaps that's why you're having trouble - there could be several answers.

Comment: He put his plot in GeoGebra. THere is clearly an area defined by 4 curves, just click on the link https://www.geogebra.org/calculator/kn3hc8y5

Comment: Posted computed area with scatter for the shape